# Integer Arithmetics Going Wild

Tags: c++, implementation, integer-arithmetic

Please, could somebody explain what's happening under the hood there?
The example runs on an Intel machine. Would the behavior be the same on other architectures?

Actually, I have a hardware counter which overruns every now and then, and I have to make sure that the intervals are always computed correctly. I thought that integer arithmetics should always do the trick but when there is a sign change, binary subtraction yields an overflow bit which appears to be actually interpreted as the sign.

Do I really have to handle the sign by myself or is there a more elegant way to compute the interval regardless of the hardware or the implementation?

TIA

```
  std::cout << "\nTest integer arithmetics\n";
  int8_t iFirst = -2;
  int8_t iSecond = 2;
  int8_t iResult = iSecond - iFirst;
  std::cout << "\n" << std::to_string(iSecond) << " - " << std::to_string(iFirst) << " = " << std::to_string(iResult);
  iResult = iFirst - iSecond;
  std::cout << "\n" << std::to_string(iFirst) << " - " << std::to_string(iSecond) << " = " << std::to_string(iResult);
  iFirst = SCHAR_MIN + 1; iSecond = SCHAR_MAX - 2;
  iResult = iSecond - iFirst;
  std::cout << "\n" << std::to_string(iSecond) << " - " << std::to_string(iFirst) << " = " << std::to_string(iResult);
  iResult = iFirst - iSecond;
  std::cout << "\n" << std::to_string(iFirst) << " - " << std::to_string(iSecond) << " = " << std::to_string(iResult) << "\n\n";
```

And this is what I get:

```
Test integer arithmetics
2 - -2 = 4
-2 - 2 = -4
125 - -127 = -4
-127 - 125 = 4
```

Answer (score 2):

What happens with `iResult = iFirst - iSecond` is that first both variables `iFirst` and `iSecond` are [*promoted*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion#Integer_promotions) to `int` due to [usual arithmetic conversion](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion#Usual_arithmetic_conversions). The result is an `int`. That `int` result is *truncated* to `int8_t` for the assignment (in effect, the top 24 bits of the 32-bit `int` is cut away).

The `int` result of `-127 - 125` is `-252`. With [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) representation that will be `0xFFFFFF04`. Truncation only leaves the `0x04` part. Therefore `iResult` will be equal to `4`.

Comment: Thanks to both of you for the immediate answers. In fact, the counter is 32 bits although the behavior is the same as with 8 bits.

Comment: I just gave it a shot with 64bit integers, and the result is still the same. 
At least, now it is confirmed that I have to take the overflow into account on my side.

Answer (score 1):

the problem is that your variable is 8 bit. 8 bits can hold up to 256 numbers. So, your variables can only represent numbers within -128~127 range. Any number out of that range will give wrong output. Both of your last calculations produce numbers beyond the variable's range (252 and -252). There is no elegant or even possible way to handle it as it is. You can only handle the overflow bit yourself.

PS. This is not hardware problem. Any processor would give same results.